# How do I get my volume keys working?

Tags: keyboard, multimedia

My laptop's media keys (volume up/down/mute) are detected via `xev` and `showkey`. I can go into System Settings > Keyboard > Shortcuts and set the volume controls with the media keys. However when I try to use the keys they do not function properly.

I tried setting the keys and rebooting the system but that hasn't worked. Any ideas?

System Info:

- Dell Latitude E6500
- Ubuntu 12.04.1

Answer (score 0):

A bit late I know, and only a suggestion (rather than a definite answer) but have you tried looking at the output of `xmodmap -pke | grep <keycode_from_xev>` (may just be the command line version of that path you tried but worth a go)

If you haven't, and the output is something like  `keyode <...> =`
then it might be fixed by creating a `.xmodmapfile` with the line `keycode <...> = XF86AudioLowerVolume` (and `XF86AudioRaiseVolume` for the other key).

You can then use the file with the command `xmodmap .xmodmapfile`

Also it would be quite helpful if you put `xmodmap -pke | grep XF86Audio` into the terminal to see if there are any keycodes bound to that.

If that's what you meant you tried when you said you tried "setting the keys" then I apologise.